# How to transform Momentum strategy scripts to alert in pinescript?

Tags: finance, pine-script

Can anyone help me to transform the mom strategy pine-script codes to the alert?
Here is the code:

```
//@version=3
strategy("Momentum Strategy", overlay=true)
length = input(12) 
price = close

momentum(seria, length) =>
    mom = seria - seria[length]
    mom

mom0 = momentum(price, length)
mom1 = momentum(mom0, 1)

if (mom0 > 0 and mom1 > 0)
    stop_price = high+syminfo.mintick
    strategy.entry("MomLE", strategy.long, stop=stop_price, comment="MomLE", qty=2)
else
    strategy.cancel("MomLE")

if (mom0 < 0 and mom1 < 0)
    stop_price = low - syminfo.mintick
    strategy.entry("MomSE", strategy.short, stop=stop_price, comment="MomSE", qty=2)
else
    strategy.cancel("MomSE")
```

Comment: Have a look at the `alertcondition()` function.

Comment: I've written an in-depth article about [the `alertcondition()` function](https://kodify.net/tradingview/alerts/program-alerts/). It probably helps to better understand how to code alert conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone help me to transform the mom strategy pine-script codes to the alert?

To translate the strategy code into an indicator that can generate alerts, there are four things to do:

1. Replace the `strategy()` function with `study()`.
2. Remove the strategy specific code. In this case that are the `strategy.entry()` and `strategy.exit()` functions.
3. Then add [the `alertcondition()` function](https://kodify.net/tradingview/alerts/program-alerts/) to code the alert condition. For this you can use the same logic as the strategy used.
4. Add some kind of output function to your code*.

Here's how that would look:

```
//@version=3
study("Momentum Alert", overlay=true)
length = input(12) 
price = close

momentum(seria, length) =>
    mom = seria - seria[length]
    mom

mom0 = momentum(price, length)
mom1 = momentum(mom0, 1)

// Create alert conditions
alertcondition(condition=mom0 > 0 and mom1 > 0,
     message="Momentum increased")

alertcondition(condition=mom < 0 and mom1 < 0,
     message="Momentum decreased")

// Output something
plot(series=mom0)
```

---

*: TradingView's `alertcondition()` function is not a so-called 'output function'. But each indicator does need such a function (like, for instance, for plotting, colouring, or creating shapes). Else you get the ['script must have at least one output function call' error](https://kodify.net/tradingview/errors/one-output-function-call/).

That's why I added the `plot()` function in the example code above, even though it isn't strictly speaking necessarily for your question.